# code refactoring, how to elegantly overwrite object values

Tags: javascript, angularjs

so I have a call to factory and after everything goes fine I want to reset the values of imput fields and as you can see in the code below I do this by hand.

```
vm.submitRequest = () = > {
    requestedBooksFactory.requestBook(vm.title, vm.author, vm.link, vm.destination, vm.currentUser, vm.comments)
        .then(function (newbook) {
        let booksInTotal = vm.requestedBooks.allBooks.length + 1;

        vm.requestedBooks.allBooks.push(newbook);
        vm.requestedBooks.header = requestedBooksFactory.requestedText(booksInTotal);
    }).then(() = > {
        vm.title = '';
        vm.author = '';
        vm.link = '';
        vm.comments = '';
        vm.destination = false;
        vm.submitted = false;
    })
}
```

I dont like the way this looks, but cant come up with a way to solve it

Comment: make a reset function in vm and call it like: vm.reset()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My own way to refactore this code:

```
vm.submitRequest = submitRequest;

/**************/

function submitRequest() {
    return requestBook()
        .then(bookReceived)
        .then(clearController);

}

function requestBook() {
    return requestedBooksFactory.requestBook(vm.title, vm.author, vm.link, vm.destination, vm.currentUser, vm.comments);
}

function bookReceived(book) {
    vm.requestedBooks.allBooks.push(book);
    vm.requestedBooks.header = requestedBooksFactory.requestedText(vm.requestedBooks.allBooks.length);
}

function clearController() {
    vm.title = '';
    vm.author = '';
    vm.link = '';
    vm.comments = '';
    vm.destination = false;
    vm.submitted = false;
}
```

Source should not to be too zipped. It should be readable and clear.
Don't use anonymous functions for long methods.
They was designed for short iterators.
Don't afraid function names, they here for you, not for parser.
For parser you'll use obfuscators.

---

But I try to post what are you looking for :)

```
   function clearController() {
     ['title', 'author', 'link', 'comments'].forEach(f => {vm[f] = '';});
     ['destination', 'submitted'].forEach(f => {vm[f] = false;});
   }
```

Comment: very neat, just what I was looking for. much obliged :)